# Torch doesnt see gpu on gcloud with deep learning containers

Tags: python-3.x, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, pytorch, gcloud

I am trying to run some python code on kubernetes in GCloud, I am using pytorch and for the base image i am using gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/pytorch-gpu/.

Everything spins up fine, and my model trains but only using CPU. When i run the following

```
>>> import torch
>>> torch.cuda.is_available()
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py:52: UserWarning: CUDA    initialization: CUDA driver initialization failed, you might not have a CUDA gpu. (Triggered internally at  /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1614378098133/work/c10/cuda/CUDAFunctions.cpp:109.)
return torch._C._cuda_getDeviceCount() > 0
False
```

But this is the output of nvidia-smi

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.67       Driver Version: 418.67       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla K80           Off  | 00000000:00:04.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   62C    P8    32W / 149W |     11MiB / 11441MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The version of pytorch is the one that is given by the base image, so i am not exactly sure how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

```
>>> torch.__version__
'1.8.0'
```

EDIT TWO:

```
>>> torch.version.cuda
'11.1'
```

Comment: Please, update the question with the PyTorch version: `torch.__version__`

Comment: In order to understand your case, I need some more information. Have you followed the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/gpu-instance-groups) to create an instance group with GPUs added to each instance? Also, after creating the instance group, you should install the device drivers. So the application can access the device,[here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/install-drivers-gpu). Have you installed the driver?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did not create the node pool myself. Only tasked with getting this to work. Under node pool details I can see 1 x NVIDIA Tesla K80 as the gpu accelerator pr node.

Comment: @Berriel I have updated with torrch version

Comment: @Shadesfear as a sanity check, could you please provide the output of `torch.version.cuda`?

Comment: @Berriel I have updated it now, as you see the cuda version from nvidia-smi is not the same as the one from torch.version.cuda.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have a NVIDIA driver that supports up to CUDA 10.1 and you installed a PyTorch built on CUDA 11.1. To solve that issue you can:

1. Update your NVIDIA driver to one that supports CUDA 11.1, or
2. Install a PyTorch compatible with CUDA 10.1 (which is compatible with your NVIDIA driver)

For the option 2, you can simply run the following:

```sh
pip install torch==1.8.0+cu101 torchvision==0.9.0+cu101 torchaudio==0.8.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

You can check the versions available for CUDA 10.1 in https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html (those in `cu101/`)

Comment: this made sense ,  saved the day..Thanks!